# How can you make Python Tkinter Label text resize automatically along with the root window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am trying to make a tkinter label that stays in the middle of the root window and resizes along with it.

Is there any simple way to do that with using just `.place()` - and not using `.grid()` ?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

my_label= Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', font= ('Calibri', 20))
my_label.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, anchor= CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you used sticky, you used a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the window size change and proportionally change the font size on the label.

```
from tkinter import *

i = 12

def config(event):
    global i
    i = 12
    w = root.winfo_width()
    h = root.winfo_height()
    k = min(w, h) / 200
    i = int(i + i*k)
    my_label['font'] = ('Calibri', i)


root= Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

root.bind("<Configure>", config)

my_label= Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', font= ('Calibri', i))
my_label.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, anchor= CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```